# how can i jump to a specific line in an editor when click a label in the treeviewer in jface/swt-eclipse plugin development

Tags: java, eclipse, jface

I'm doing an eclipse plugin project. I have realized a view by TreeViewer, which can read info from text and show them. 
The treeViewer has several columns and one of which shows the specific line number in a file,

just like this:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   de.toem.pattern.element.Elements  at
>   de.toem.eclipse.toolkits.util.SelectionUtils.getElements(SelectionUtils.java:36)

I have no idea how to jump to the file when  click the number, please help me..

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the source of `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.console.JavaStackTraceHyperlink` which is the code called from the Console view when you click on a class name hyperlink in a Java stack trace. This understands how to find the class, open the Java editor and go to the line number.